# 'Name' column on view being duplicated on design rerun

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, json, site-design

I've written the below JSON to create a list (with the doc library template) and create an associated view.

```
{
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "Doc lib name",
            "templateType": 101,
            "subactions": [
                 {
                    "verb": "addSPView",
                    "name": "Documents View",
                    "viewFields":[
                        "DocIcon",
                        "Name",
                        "othercolumnshere..."
                    ],
                    "query": "<GroupBy Collapse=\"False\"> <FieldRef Name=\"ColumnNameHere\" /> </GroupBy>",
                    "rowLimit": 100,
                    "isPaged": true,
                    "makeDefault": false,
                    "scope": "Default"
                }

etc...
}
```

When I run the script through a site design, it's perfect and works fine. However, when I run the same script again for whatever reason, a new 'Name' column is appended at the end of the view. And when the script is run yet again, another one is added. This doesn't happen with any other column e.g

**Run 1:**
DocIcon | Name | Other Column

**Run 2:**
DocIcon | Name | Other Column | Name

**Run 3:**
DocIcon | Name | Other Column | Name | Name

If I don't include "Name" in "viewFields" the column doesn't show in the view at all.

I'm not entirely sure whether this is expected behaviour / I'm doing something wrong, or whether this is a bug. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You’d better share your full site design json,I did not reproduce your issue.
[image]

[image]

My json:

```
$site_script = '
    {
        "$schema": "schema.json",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "verb": "createSPList",
                    "listName": "Customer Tracking",
                    "templateType": 100,
                    "subactions": [
                        {
                            "verb": "setDescription",
                            "description": "List of Customers and Orders"
                        },
                        {
                            "verb": "addSPField",
                            "fieldType": "Text",
                            "displayName": "Name",
                            "isRequired": false,
                            "addToDefaultView": true
                        },

                        {
                    "verb": "addSPView",
                    "name": "Documents View",
                    "viewFields":[
                        "Name"
                    ],
                    "query": "<GroupBy Collapse=\"False\"> <FieldRef Name=\"Name\" /> </GroupBy>",
                    "rowLimit": 100,
                    "isPaged": true,
                    "makeDefault": false,
                    "scope": "Default"
                }
                    ]
                }
            ],
                "bindata": { },
        "version": 1
    } '
```